# Defining variables by selection

Tags: qgis, select, qgis-variable

I'm working on a valve isolation project for a natural gas application. I'm a design engineer foremost, but like to play with programming and GIS applications fairly often. I've got a bit of experience with both, but Python is pretty new to me, and programming on a GIS application is also new to me.

What I would like to do, is to have the script start, and prompt for input from the user. The user would then select a line feature ("Main") in the map. I want it to store the value of a particular field ("SegmentID") of that line feature I selected to a variable called HitSegmentID. The script will then select all point features on the "valve" layer that share the same segment id. I tried doing some research on functions yesterday that involved active layer, user input, prompting dialogue boxes and selected layer, but nothing I've found yet does anything that I want.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you edit your question to include your code so far, then people can point out what you're doing wrong and make suggestions. It's hard to "point you in the right direction" without knowing where you're starting from.